# How do you understand $a\times1=a$ in Peano axioms?

Tags: arithmetic, peano-axioms

How do you understand $a\times1=a$ in Peano axioms?

This should be understood as replacing $1$ with $a$? For example, when we multiply $3$ by $2$, that means: replace each $1$ in the number three with $2$?

Is it just a replacement or is it something else?

Comment: As far as I remember there is no such Peano axiom. The usual axioms can be augmented by the usual operations, but they're given with the help of the successonr function S(a)...If you can express it that way then, perhaps, you'll understand it better...or at least will be able to re-ask your question again/

Comment: Was just reading Tao's Analysis I, and stumbled upon Peano Axioms. For natural numbers, the book says "..just as addition is iterated increment, multiplication is iterated addition"- so $a\times 1=a$ simply means $a$ added once, i.e., $a$ itself. For $3\times 2$, $3$ is added twice. The replacement analogy seems to make the process explicit, maybe someone with more expertise can comment on that.

Comment: @Manan Yes, thank you. I just want to comment about the analogy with the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement simply seems to be distributivity in disguise. Consider $$a\times b=\underbrace{(1+1+...+1)}_{\text{a times}}\times b=\underbrace{(b+b+...+b)}_{\text{a times}}$$Thus, each of the $1$ was 'replaced' by $b$ by simply distributing over $a$. The distributivity of multiplication over addition on $\Bbb N$ can be established using Peano Axioms.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, multiplication is defined by induction $0x = 0$ and $(n+1)x = nx + x$. The first step of the recurrence gives
$$ 1\times x = 0x + x = 0 + x = x.$$
Clearly you can either define the multiplication on the other side, if you wish to prove it directly in the form $x \times 1 = x$ or by proving (induction) that the multiplication is commutative.

Comment: I just want to comment about the analogy with the replacement with each 1 :)